# Timeout period elapsed prior in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2014 installed.
When I am executing query (I.E Exec sp_Updatestats) of any database, it will stops execute and display message after exact 10 minutes.

> "the timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection of the operation or the server is not responding"

I have checked,

> SQL->Properties->Connections (It's 600.)

On Other server it's also same 600 but my query executes more than 10 minutes.

while If i execute query using sql agent job then it's working, only issue with query window.

Comment: can you repro this issue everytime ,i meant to say exact 10 minutes.are you executing this remote or local

Comment: I am executing local on same server where sql has been installed.

Comment: what about repro ,can you do that consistently everytime

Comment: Yes it happens every time.

Comment: then try running update stats and try running this into a table in parallel session and update your question `while 1=1
begin
insert into sometable
select ec.last_wait_type,ec.wait_type,ec.wait_resource,ec.wait_time,lck.request_mode from sys.dm_Exec_requests ec
join
sys.dm_tran_locks lck
on lck.request_session_id=ec.session_id
where ec.session_id="your update stats session id"
waitfor delay '00:00:10'
end`

Comment: you can also use extended events to track same

Answer (score 0):

Check query execution timeout value
[image]

Comment: Checked and it's same as your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved with change in Connection properties in Login screen.
Changes Execution timeout to 0 second.